# NKAssetDownloads continue even after the app is deleted

Tags: iphone, ios, newsstand-kit

I have verified this activity on ios 6 and ios 7 using Charles; once an NKAssetDownload is initiated from an app, deleting that app *does not* cancel the download. This seems crazy to me. Is there any way to address this?

Comment: Do you run application from xcode at moment when you deleting app?

Comment: They are dev builds, but they are being run independently, outside of xcode. The process is, open the app normally (not from xcode), start download, home-button close app, delete app via long press.

I have little reason to believe this would behave different if run via xcode, though there is the possibility it could behave differently with release builds, I will check.

Comment: I think there is nothing to do with it coz its part of Newsstand and Newsstand load data in background by default. Check this http://ipadinsight.com/ios/whats-the-point-of-newsstand-automatic-background-downloads/ . So data downloaded not by your application but by iOS directly. Seems that this is iOS bug.